# Angular: I can't seem to get JavaScript functions to work, but it's not giving me any undefined errors

Tags: javascript, angular, mean-stack

My angular project isn't giving me any errors, but functions aren't working.

I'm doing a simple project trying to learn MEAN stack, and I've reached a point where my functions just aren't doing anything. I want the `decideDetail()` function to change the value of `details` so that the content displayed by `productdetail.component.html` is changed when the user clicks a certain element on the `products.component.html` template. I assume I'm linking my JavaScript file coorectly, because before I did that, it was telling me the function wasn't defined. Here are what I think are the relevant files (I've tried writing `decideDetail()` several different ways):

**products.component.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="home">Home</a>
    <a class="active" href="products">Products</a>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-6" id="0" (click)="decideDetail(details, productList[0].productDescription)">
        <a routerLink="detail" style="color: orange"> {{ productList[0]?.productName }} </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-6" id="product2">col-xl-6</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-6" id="product3">col-xl-6</div>
    <div class="col-xl-6" id="product4">col-xl-6</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-6">col-xl-6</div>
    <div class="col-xl-6">col-xl-6</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-6">col-xl-6</div>
    <div class="col-xl-6">col-xl-6</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-6">col-xl-6</div>
    <div class="col-xl-6">col-xl-6</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**products.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../data.service';
import {Product} from '../product';
import * as details from '../productdetail/productdetail.component';

declare var detailDecide: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-products',
    templateUrl: './products.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./products.component.css'],
    providers: [DataService]

})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
    productList: Product[] = [];

    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    }

    getProduct() {
        this.dataService.getproductList()
            .subscribe(products => {
                    this.productList = products;
                }
            )
    };

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getProduct();
    }

    decideDetail(a, b) {
        detailDecide.decideDetail(a, b);
    }
}
```

**js.js**

```
var detailDecide = (function (a, b) {
    return {
        decideDetail: function (a, b) {
            a = b;
            alert(b);
        }
    }
})(detailDecide || {})
```

**productdetail.component.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="home">Home</a>
    <a href="products">Products</a>
    <a class="active" href="#">Product Detail</a>
</div>

<p>
    productdetail works!
</p>

<div id="product1" #product1> {{details}}</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using `html`, `head` and `body` tags in your templates?`

Comment: I guess for a reason similar to why I can't get functions to work, lol. It's not there anymore. I've been trying everything and functions won't work.

Comment: Why are you using js file anyway? What are you trying to achieve? You are working with Angular + TS, so why mix in some js files there? :)

Comment: Well, all my information on how to use angular comes from various YouTube videos and I'm a student fresh out of a client-side scripting(JavaScript) course so anything I can do to stay within the comfort of JavaScript, I do. While trying to get the function to work, going through more videos where people are defining the functions in the component.ts files, I've learned that's simpler. I've done it one way, then the other, then both ways, lol. I'm all over the place. I have no idea what I'm missing. I may start the thing from scratch and see if trimming everything down will solve my problem.

Comment: Maybe a good idea to start over yes. Using JS like that isn't "Angularish". I suggest you the TOH tutorial, that is a good idea to get the basics down: https://angular.io/tutorial I mean, since you have for example used `body` tags in you components, which is not what we do, it can be a good idea to just start from scratch with the help of the tutorial? :)